# Mean Value Theorem and Vector Valued Functions

Tags: real-analysis, vectors

Say I have the following vector valued function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $f(x) = ({x^2},{x^3})$. Clearly the derivative $f'(x) = ({2x},{3x^2})$. But, does there exist a $0 < b < 1$ such that $f'(b) = f(1) - f(0)$? Obviously simple arithmetic says no, but doesn't this contradict the mean value theorem?

Comment: The theorem is only for $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.

Comment: There is no exact analog of the mean value theorem for vector-valued functions

Comment: $\exists\ c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ such that $2 = 2$ and $3 = 6c_{2}$ where $0 < c_{\rm i} < 1$. $i = 1, 2$.